# HTML/CSS - Reducing window size but nav menu stuck on top right of the screen

Tags: html, css, position

Let me please say that I am very new at HTML/CSS so excuse my very sloppy code. Basically, all I want is a header with my name in it and then my nav bar on the top right. But when I resize the window, the nav bar is stuck to the top right and will overlap my heading. I just want it to stay put!

I'm not sure if this is enough information but I'll put my CSS code below. I've been trying for over an hour to get it to resize from the top left. I tried position:fixed / right:0px but nothing happens. If you guys can help I'll be forever grateful.

```
div#wrapper {
    width: 98%;
    margin: auto;
}

div.header {
background-color:black;
height: 80px;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
}

div.menu {
    width:600px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

div.menu  p {
display:inline-block;
float:right;
margin-top:0px;

}

div.menu a { 
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 30px 10px 29px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: -5px;
    color: black;
    background-color:white;
    font-family: Trajan Pro;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    font-size:16px;

}
```

Thanks so much in advance!!

Comment: can you provide some example on fiddle? I don't know what kind a problem you are in. -Sven

Comment: Here's the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/4C8t8/

And here's the imgur link: http://imgur.com/jKrRvTi

Basically, I don't want my nav bar to cover my name and I just want it to stay to the right so I have to scroll to see it. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is this:
You want to resize the window, but you want your navigation bar not to be resized. If this is what you ask what you should do is simple.

Your current child-parent relation is like this (if I understood correctly)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="navigationbar"></div>
</div>
```

What you want is this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu"></div>
</div>
<div id="navigationbar"></div>
```

This way your navigation bar div won't be resized or won't change position. To make it stuck in top right here is the css code you need:

```
.navigationbar{position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;}
```

If this does not solve your problem please explain how you resize or share a link here so we can understand easier.

Comment: It didn't seem to work :( I commented on someone else's post to provide a link. If you want, have a look!! Basically, I don't want it fixed to the top right of my reduced screen. I want the web-page to keep it's original sizing :)